# Photorec : No file found in a full 64GB SD card. What to do?

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card, data-corruption, photorec

Recently my memory card (Samsung Evo 64GB, almost full) was showing 'corrupt' on my Tablet. So I tried to recover the important details using `photorec`. It ran for around 1 hour but 0 files have been found.

the output is something like this

```
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
 1 * FAT32 LBA                1   0  1 61055  63 32  125040640 [NO NAME]
```

Please help

Comment: Try testdisk for recovery and make sure the right device is chosen!

Comment: Did you have all the filetypes selected? Did you have Paranoid or Keep corrupted files selected? Was the card actually being read (if it was in a usb reader, was it "flashing", the reader works, etc)? How much was it able to read, maybe it was only left with a sector or two accessible

Comment: The following link and links from it can help you analyze the problem, and if you are lucky, solve it. I think PhotoRec is a good tool for this purpose, but there are a few things to try in order to get access to the card. [Analysis of the problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Answer (score 0):

Try some of these Linux tool (apt install them on Ubuntu):

- gddrescue
- myrescue
- safecopy